# Rotate and Scale UIImageView with animation

Tags: iphone, core-animation

How can I get a UIImageView to rotate itself 90° counter-clockwise and have the same UIImageView scale to fill the entire iPhone screen with animation at speeds of one-second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using .tranform and M_PI for rotation, and changing the frame size

Answer (score 3):

Create a CGAffineTransform that embodies your rotation and scale, then set it as the transform property of your view inside of an animation block which has a 1 second duration.